# Matching a sentence with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to grep for the full sentence containing a search term. I've tried

```
grep (^.|\.\s).*searchterm.*(\.\s|\n)
```

but it's not working and I'm not sure why.

To clarify: I want stdout to print the full sentence of the search term. I am using grep to search through a single text file.

As an example, if my file has

"`Foo blah. Blah blah searchterm blah blah. Foo bar."`

I want stdout to print `Blah blah searchterm blah blah`

Comment: Would you give an example of what you might want as a search term, and what you would want it to match?

Comment: It's hard to get a read on what you're trying to search for with that regex, because the regex is somewhat redundant. For example the highlighted part (^.`|\.\s`).*searchterm.*(\.\s|\n) will never be matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because normal grep uses `BRE` in which you have to write capturing groups as `\(...\)` and also the alternation operator as `\|` . `(` or `)` or `|` alone would match it's corresponding literal `(` , `)`, `|` chars.

```
grep '\(^.\|\.\s\).*searchterm.*\(\.\s\|\n\)'
```

or

```
grep '\(^.\|\.[[:space:]]\).*searchterm.*\(\.[[:space:]]\|\n\)'
```

or

Enable `-E` or `-P` parameter.

```
grep -P '(^.|\.\s).*searchterm.*(\.\s|\n)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-sed`, this will strip away anything before and after the sentence containing searchterm:

```
sed -n -r '/searchterm/ s/^|(.*\. (.*))(searchterm[^.]*\.).*/\2\3/ ; s/\..*/\./p'
```